# При работе код выдаёт ошибку: for row in self.level: AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'level'

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
class Map:
    def __init__(self):
        self.level=[
            "------------------"
            "                "
            "                "
            "                "
            "                "
            "                "
            "                "
            "                "
            "                "
            "                "
            "                "
            "                "
            "                "
            "                "
            "                "
            "                "
            "                "
            "                "
            "                "
            "----------------"
            ]
        self.object1=pygame.surface((40,40))
        self.object1.fill((123,321,234))
    def render(self,screen):
        x=0
        y=0
        for row in self.level:
            for col in row:
                if col=="-":
                    screen.blit(object1,(x,y))
                x+=40
            y+=40
            x=0
```

def filling_screen(self,screen,color,m_character,cube,bullet,information,Start_menu,mouse,map):

```
    screen.fill(color)
    map.render(screen,screen)<<-------------тут вызывается render
    m_character.render(screen)
    for i in range(len(bullet)):
        bullet[i].render(screen)
    cube.render(screen)
    information.render(screen)
    #Start_menu.render(screen,0)
    #mouse.render(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

тут вызывается render

Что с ним не так ?Помогите

Comment: `self.` пропустили в `screen.blit(object1,(x,y))` т.е. должно быть `screen.blit( self.object1, (x,y) )`

Comment: Метод `render` для типа `Map` принимает **два** аргумента (экземпляр класса и `screen`), а данный вызов `map.render(screen,screen) -> Map.render(map, screen, screen)` передает **три** аргумента, что должно приводить к исключению `TypeError`.

Comment: а если убрать один screen        то происходит это                                                        
            render() missing 1 required positional argument: 'screen'

Comment: Тогда приведите полностью весь код, чтобы не гадать.

Comment: Всё я решил проблему ошибка оказалась сверх простой.

Comment: @Yaroslav_Fox По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: Просто забыл дописать "()" когда переменной присваивал класс